# Confused about How to use Dialog Control

Tags: android

everbody .I am trying to make a simple application .I have a main activity and a Layout file called myview.xml .I have two EditText and one button control inside this layout file and I will use it for showing Dialog Control.How can I get these values coming from dialog control and set in the MainActivity

this is what I have so far

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    btnDisplay=(Button)findViewById(R.id.btndisplay);
    btnDisplay.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            dialog=new Dialog(MainActivity.this); 
            dialog.setContentView(R.layout.myview);
            edtName=(EditText)dialog.findViewById(R.id.edtname);
            edtSname=(EditText)dialog.findViewById(R.id.edtsurname);
            dialog.show();
```

//

Answer (score 0):

You should make one button inside dialog and on this button click you should dismiss the dialog and   get the edittext value like this

```
                       String name = edtName.getText().toString();
                       String sname = edtSname.getText().toString();
```

Comment: But I cant get the controls located layout file from MainActivity.For example   edtName=(EditText)dialog.findViewById(R.id......);